# How to Hyperlink the Citation

Tags: pdf, citing

At present I am
using WinEdt v 5.5. My question is, how can I hyperlink the citation such
that by clicking the cited number in the article(of a .pdf file) it will
automatically take me to corresponding reference(in the same .pdf file)?

Comment: Tried to use the [`hyperref`package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Answer (score 2):

That you are using the editor WinEdt v5.5 has nothing to do with the hyperlinks for citations.  But the current version of WinEdt is 8.x so you should consider to update.

To get hyperlinks for your citations, add the line `\usepackage{hyperref}` in your preamble.  Depending on the document class and packages you use, `hyperref` should generally be the last called package.  Use `texdoc hyperref` from terminal for more information or visit [package `hyperref`on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).